# Given a line (x = c), and a point (p) NOT on the line, and a distance (d) how do I find a point on the line at that distance?

Tags: geometry

Assume the d is at least as large as the minimum distance to the line.

If it matters what I really want is given a rectangle's height and width and a circle size to calculate the center points of the largest number of circles that fit the area without coming closer then a fixed distance to each other, nor having more then two circles across.   I'll be using the information to drive a laser and make a real world object...

I'm sure there are some other ways I could solve this, I just happen to think this one would be simplest for me.

Comment: Pythagorean Theorem?

Comment: You know that every point on the line $x=c$ has coordinates of the form $(c,y)$ so you need to find the correct value of $y$. You should expect as many as two solutions because a circle of radius $d$ could intersect the line twice. Let $p$ have coordinates $(a,b)$ and the distance formula will give you an equation you can solve for $y$.